# MPI not loading in python script despite mpi4py installed?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I have installed the mpi4py lib, and can import it by itself, but when i try to reference MPI i get an error saying it is not a part of mpu4py?

See below for an example of the issue...

I don't understand what is going on?  Why this won't work?  Do i need to install a different version of mpi4py, but whey is there no docs on this issue, it just seems to work for everyone else?

I am under windows 11.

I have done searches but no one else seems to have this issue?

From Python Session....

```
D:\PROJECTS\DiffuseBTCGuess\src\guided-diffusion> python
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mpi4py
>>> from mpi4py import MPI
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing MPI: The specified module could not be found.
```

Added:

```
D:\PROJECTS\DiffuseBTCGuess\src\guided-diffusion> ls c:\users\hanso\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mpi4py
    Directory: C:\users\hanso\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\mpi4py
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Nam
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM                futures
d-----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM                include
d-----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM                util
d-----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM                __pycache__
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM           6316 bench.py    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            351 bench.pyi    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            774 dl.pyi    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM          44966 libmpi.pxd    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            193 mpi.cfg    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM        1076224 MPI.cp38-win_amd64.pyd    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM           3964 MPI.pxd    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM          51995 MPI.pyi    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM             27 py.typed    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM           9050 run.py    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            205 run.pyi    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM             56 __init__.pxd    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM           5279 __init__.py    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            793 __init__.pyi    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM            165 __main__.py    
-a----        2024-03-17   5:36 AM             22 __main__.pyi
```

Sorry if this gets mangled, but as you can see when i type
pip show mpi4py
... it lists the above directory for site-packagses, and that is what is in that directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can import mpi4py by itself"?

Comment: Under the hood, `mpi4py` will try to dynamically load the MPI library it was built with, the error message might be related to this (e.g. the right MPI library is not in the library path)

Comment: when i type pip list it shows mpi4py as installed @GillesGouaillardet.  I can import it as Sorry my python session got mangled above.  If should show me loading the mpi4py fine using the command import mpi4py. But when i try the line from mpi4py import MPI, i get the above ImportError?  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling?  How can insure pip installs the correct mpi4py if I am not installing the full version with MPI?

Comment: I added and cleaned up the question above, hopefully it makes more sense now.. I can see the MPI in the site-package/mpi4y directory, but it doesn't seem to recognize it?  Is it because of the permissions perhaps?

Comment: You'll need to install the MPI libraries, and mpi4py will need to pick those up.

Comment: "How can insure pip installs the correct mpi4py if I am not installing the full version with MPI?": you can't: it looks like, for at least Python 3.8, you'll need to install the MPI library yourself.

Comment: "I can see the MPI in the site-package/mpi4y directory, but it doesn't seem to recognize it?": that is not the MPI library: it's still a wrapper around it, related to mpi4py. The actual MPI library would have a DLL extension (as per the error message), and would probably located somewhere else.

Comment: @9769953 You sir are a genius and a gentleman!  Thank-you, worked like a charm once I installed microsoft MPI, and made sure to reinstall the mpi4py, and it works fine now!
Thank-you, saved me a great deal of struggle today!!!